# How to ensure webpage elements load correctly after selenium execute_script call before scraping

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have a project where I am attempting to scrape data from a database-type webpage, but find its load times are very unpredictable. The button clicks call JavaScript functions that change the buttons in the frame. I have developed a script that navigates through the scriptural book, then chapters, then verses, until it gets to the "bottom" level of the tree and returns information about which talks used that particular verse as a citation. The goal is to collect all the data about each verse cited, by whom, when, etc.

My current focus is to just get all the data downloaded, but that is proving to be tricky. I have tried to use `browser.implicitly_wait` to get the behaviour I am wanting, and have also tried `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "citationindex"))` and that hasn't seemed to work either.

The current setup is shown below. It works as follows:

1. Selenium opens the base url in Chrome and calls the recursive function
2. `dig_into_citations` is called on the browser which recursively starts search through the links in the 'citationindex' or 'citationindex2' element.
3. The `get_citationindex` function is called first to determine which one the data is in, as it appears to switch back and forth, depending on what level of the tree you are at. If anyone knows why this is happening, that would be hugely helpful). This 'waits' for the citationindex element to load, which is determines by checking when link elements appear inside one of the two possible elements. Hacky but this seems to work most of the time.
4. Then the logic in `dig_into_citations` checks to see if we are at the base level yet, which is where the talks appear. If so, I'll collect the data somehow (not worried about the details now) but am currently just printing out for debugging purposes.
5. If not yet at the base level, then we are looking at either books, chapters, or verses and want to dig into each of those. I do this by running the javascript function within the `onclick` attribute of each of the button links (which has the form `getFilter('1', '101')` where the number of arguments depends on the level). I am passing the script through as well to store as the id for each talk.

The problem I am having is that call to `execute_script` basically just updates the current webpage with new buttons, and it's not clear how long that takes each time, so I'm putting a 1 second sleep in before each iteration. I find anything slower causes it to choke.

Like I say, I have tried the "wait-until" functionality in Selenium but it hasn't seemed to function as expected. I suspect that this is again because running the script in each case causes the elements inside the 'citationindex' (or 'citationindex2') function to update but the element itself is already there and already "loaded" so maybe that's why the wait-until stuff isn't working.

Any insights into how this process could be improved and made robust would be greatly appreciated. If I am going about this in the wrong way, it would also help to know if there is a simpler approach to get at all the data I'm looking for rather than this rickety recursion through button click hell. Thanks in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time


def get_citationindex(browser):
    """
    Gets the name of the citationindex element that contains the links of interest.
    """
    CITATION_ID_NAMES = ['citationindex', 'citationindex2']

    # Gets the HTML associated with both citation index elements and attempts to find links inside
    def get_soup_list(browser):
        citation_id_elems = [browser.find_element_by_id(x).get_attribute('innerHTML') for x in CITATION_ID_NAMES]
        citation_id_soups = [BeautifulSoup(x, features="lxml") for x in citation_id_elems]
        soup_list = [soup for soup in citation_id_soups if soup.find_all('a')]
        return soup_list

    # This runs until the page has actually loaded and the links are found inside the proper citationindex element
    soup_list = []
    while not soup_list:
        soup_list = get_soup_list(browser)   # ! this hack is not great

    # the BeautifulSoup object of the citation index element is returned (i.e. for 'citationindex' or 'citationindex2')
    citationindex_soup = soup_list[0]
    return citationindex_soup


def dig_into_citations(browser, script=''):
    """
    Recursive function that digs into the citations (through book, chapter, and verse) until it find the talk references.
    It operates by calling the javascript functions on the page.
    """
    soup = get_citationindex(browser)

    # the desired links are the only ones with 'div' tags
    links = [x for x in soup.find_all('a') if x.find('div')]
    talks = [x for x in links if "getTalk" in x.get('onclick')]
    header = soup.find(class_='volumetitle')

    if talks:
        for k in talks:
            ref = k.find(class_='reference').text
            title = k.find(class_='talktitle').text
            print(script, header.text, ref, title)
    else:
        for k in links:
            script = k.get('onclick')
            browser.execute_script(script)
            time.sleep(1)  # ! this hack is also not great
            dig_into_citations(browser, script)


# Run a test case for one particular book
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
browser.get('https://scriptures.byu.edu/#::fNYNY7267e401074')
dig_into_citations(browser)
```

> Note I am running this with Python 3.8 with `selenium=3.141.0` and `beautifulsoup4=4.9.3` using Selenium driver for Chrome 87

Comment: If you know there will be different content inside the element, you can check for the changing of the text values. You might have to be careful with getting an error for checking an element while it is outside DOM. What you do is create a loop where you check if the value has changed every say 25 milliseconds, if it does you are done so exist. If it doesn't you can set an overall timer, that when exceeded will break the loop or possibly catch an exception if the element disappears (at that point you can use the normal check of element existence.)

Comment: The javaScript ```browser.execute_script(script)``` always return a new URL. You seem to have utilize BS4 which is great, have you thought about using requests module over selenium. Basically do a request and pass the content to bs4. From the parsing, you can generate the URL yourself and do another request/parsing based on your needs.

Comment: For example, before executing the script, the url was ```https://scriptures.byu.edu/#::fNYNY7267e401074```. JS script value was: ```getFilter('116', '1')```. URL changed to ```https://scriptures.byu.edu/#::fNYNY7267e40107401```.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did try developing a function to form the urls (by converting the arguments in the `getFilter` function to hex values and such) but was having the same problem with load times. I thought requests doesn't work when you are loading a page that requires JavaScript functions to run?

Comment: I should also clarify: when I use `requests.get` on any of those urls you mentioned, I'm not getting a response that includes the elements I need, meaning there is some additional content loaded by JavaScript after the response, if I understand it correctly

Comment: Right, did not think about dynamic content. Any chance you can post output of what you are looking to get. The question is well describe.. having an output you allow to understand better what is the printout you are looking for.